# Unknown meta-convention, "-By XYZ"?

Tags: discussion, edits, revisions-list

I just noticed when I revisited this site that someone had edited my answer to the [Naming the Tavern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63536/naming-the-tavern) question here.

No big deal, I just wanted to know if it signified something.

Basically, [Joe Philips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/20471/joe-phillips) added `-By Joe` to [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/63570/revisions).

Was there a reason for this, other than to get the editor badge?

I noticed that another user, [Fosco](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150168/fosco) did the same to [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/63538/revisions) provided by [Chacha102](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131779/chacha102), hence my question.

Comment: It *might* be that they were the ones who originally suggested those names, and simply wish to be acknowledged. (Just guessing)

Comment: Not my answer, that is, they could've suggested those names *as well*, but I did not read my answer from anywhere, I just rolled with the "Prancing Pony" name and thought unicorns would be better. Perhaps that's what happened with the Chacha102 answer, and perhaps they thought I had posted theirs, could be.

Comment: Fosco was staking a claim - http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/140680

Comment: [> If I added one of yours, go ahead and edit in 'By {Your Name}' – Chacha102](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63536/146482) (first comment)

Comment: however, an unhandled exception is not *so* uncommon that Cacha102 couldn't have made it up himself...

Comment: @Lasse, I only edited answers from ChaCha because he posted our suggestions from chat.   I did not realize one of yours was edited.

Answer (score 2):

The contest existed in The Tavern chat room for days before Chacha102 was brought in on it and made it an official thing.  Many names were posted and starred in the chat room, for which the [transcripts are available](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/140680).

Chacha102 opened the meta post and posted some of the existing entries, informing us to add our names as edits.  I added mine, editing only Chacha102 answers.  It looks like your entry was previously suggested (in chat) by JoePhillips, and he edited your answer.